# How to use Qiskit's Iterative Amplitude Estimation?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I want to use IterativeAmplitudeEstimation to estimate the amplitude of a single qubit inside a big circuit (*denoted as A*). The oracle is a simple Z gate applied on that qubit line, and it marks |1>. The diffuser is made according to the entire space of A circuit. In order to use IterativeAmplitudeEstimation, I first make my Grover Iterator (G = -A S_0 Adagger Oracle), and then pass A and G to EstimationProblem, along with objective qubit, i.e. the one who's amplitude I want to estimate, and its the last qubit of A, though I'm unsure about this.

[image]

I'm unsure whether I've put the correct values in epsilon_target and alpha parameters or not. Now, I am getting some values of estimation, but I suspect they are incorrect, they're much lower than what I expected (like 0.08 instead of 0.8). Could someone tell my how to correctly set the values of epsilon_target and alpha, also what exactly has to be put in objective_qubits in EstimationProblem?